# Create Serial Number with a String in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am using the following code in oracle on create record trigger to create a serial number. I want my serial number like `LM0001` . Using LM000 STRING WITH NUMBER and concat both to generate the serial number. I am getting error `ora-06502`. Need help where i am doing wrong. Where should i modify the code

```
DECLARE
VCAN varchar2(40);
L number (10);
BEGIN
 SELECT MAX(SL_NO)INTO VCAN FROM LAND_MANAGEMENT;
IF VCAN > 0 THEN
  L := VCAN + 1;
  :LAND_MANAGEMENT.SL_NO := 'LM000' || L;
ELSE
    :LAND_MANAGEMENT.SL_NO := 'LM000' || 1;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  :LAND_MANAGEMENT.SL_NO := 'LM000'|| 1;
END;
```

Comment: VCAN is a string that includes LM; you need to remove the LM before you can add 1. Use dbms_output to see what the variables hold, to debug it. And having four fixed zeros doesn't match the pattern you say you want, even for #1.  What happens when L is 10, or 100? Anyway, why aren't you using a sequence?

Comment: You shouldn't save LM, only save number value and concat desired character on display only.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using sequence

> create a sequence

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE LMANAGEMENT_SEQ 
  START WITH 21   
 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999   
 MINVALUE 0   
 NOCYCLE  
 CACHE 20  
 NOORDER;
```

sql query in `when-create-record` trigger

```
select 'LM' || to_char(lmanagement_seq.nextval, '000000') INTO      
:land_management.sl_no
from dual;
```